# BackEnd and FrontEnd solution to power potentially billion of web pages?

Tags: frameworks, content-management-system

consider this : http://www.webpagetest.org/ every tested website, gets a URL like www.webpagetest.org/example.com/ after example.com is tested again. www.webpagetest.org/example.com is updated with the latest results. And old result is shifted to www.webpagetest.org/example.com/2/ Now if we test a million web sites, million of web pages will supposedly be created. Now either a simple html page can be written to hard disk and called upon when user visits old page www.webpagetest.org/example.com/2/ or it can be stored in a database.
for this kind of architecture ... what would we need ? CMS or some kind of framework ..

What can be used for this kind of website?

Answer (score 0):

What you're talking about can vary widely depending on whether you're going to generate a page for every website on the internet or only the ones that people attempt to visit.  You could dynamically fetch the data when the user attempts to check their URL (e.g. http://webpagetest.org/myurl.com).  This way the server would not get killed by the infinite requests.

Also keep in mind that you need to actually have millions of visitors to the website in order to require powerful servers.  You can code something like this with many different languages / CMS / frameworks, but the real issue (if it is successful) is going to be systems administrator's job to monitor uptime, server resources, scaling the application across many servers, and optimizing the database.

**EDIT**

Some examples are Ruby on Rails ( http://rubyonrails.org/ ), CodeIgniter ( http://codeigniter.com/ ), CakePHP ( http://cakephp.org/ ), Expression Engine ( http://expressionengine.com/ ), Django ( https://www.djangoproject.com/ ) to name some of the best

Comment: i do want http://webpagetest.org/myurl.com to work. But there is another requirement, "we archive the old results too". This is where it gets ugly. And the technology of backend becomes extremely important. What kind of framework provides robust tools for such kind of massive site.

Comment: I would recommend Ruby, Django, or PHP.  Depending on a million factors that are beyond the scope of your question and too lengthy to discuss here.

Comment: I've added some examples in my original answer above.